# The requested user 'chrisb@domainname.com' is invalid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Microsoft Graph sometimes returns a strange result

Client Error:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars resulted in a 404 Not Found
```

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUser",
        "message": "The requested user 'chrisb@domain_name.com' is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c229f76d-a9d0-4441-b663-b34f4996cddb",
            "date": "2017-11-21T01:23:18"
        }
    }
}
```

That issue seems to be strange for me, since I know the user exists since I can login under it.

What I do:

1. I use stored refresh token to get access token.
2. Using that access token I try to get list of all user calendars.
3. At that point it return me fail message.

Question:

What does that error mean - since user is 100% present at Microsoft (I able to get auth token from refresh token and able to login under that user)

Comment: Are you sure this user has a valid Exchange Mailbox (i.e. can you access it via Outlook)? Not all user's necessarily have a Mailbox (and by extension a Calendar).

Comment: yes, is user that pay to microsoft for account and have full access to outlook and calendars. Even more: user able to authorize my application, exchange the the key to refresh token.

Comment: Authorization and tokens are handled by Azure Active Directory, not Microsoft Graph which is why I ask. You can have a valid user in AD without a mailbox set up in Exchange Online.

Comment: Well, user is 100% exists at Exchange and able to receive and send emails as well as able to manage calendars from online and from desctop outlook application. Even more, that error seems to appear randomly now. So some time user is able to list calendar via call, some time it error out.

Comment: Is this mailbox in Exchange Online or is this a Hybrid Exchange configuration?

Comment: Exchange Online.

Comment: I've been unable to replicate this at all. Given the length of time and odd behavior, I'd suggest opening a support ticket with Microsoft. It sounds like something is wrong with either this mailbox or the tenant itself.

Comment: the problem that microsoft report bug point to stackoverflow. also i notice that all times i have that problem the x-ms-ags-diagnostic header contain {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_6","ADSiteName":"SAN"}}

Comment: Stack Overflow is the recommended place for development questions but it is a community of volunteers. For issues with your account/tenant, you'll need to open up a support incident.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue for some MS users only whom specially has very old account, I was passing email of microsoft user like : following
let userInfo = {email: user.email}
let apiParams = {token: access_token, event: newEvent,calendarId: msUserInfo.calendarId, user:userInfo}

**Solution:**
After I had issue, I have remove 'user' parameter from api and it works for me.
I have set now as following.
I have used Node, node-outlook

```
 const outlook = require('node-outlook');
 let newEvent = {
            "Subject": objUpdate.title,
            "Body": {
              "ContentType": "HTML",
              "Content": objUpdate.description
            },
            "Start": {
              "DateTime": moment('startDate').toISOString(),
              "TimeZone": objUpdate.timeZone
            },
            "End": {
              "DateTime": moment('endDate').toISOString(),
              "TimeZone": objUpdate.timeZone
            }
        };


  outlook.calendar.createEvent({token: access_token, event: newEvent ,calendarId: msUserInfo.calendarId
     },async function(error, result){
            if (error) {
                console.log("error: -",error)
                throw "Microsoft Calendar Api Err."
            }else if (result) {
                 console.log("Result -")
            }
            });
```